# python queuelib: Get size of queue

Tags: python, queue, fifo

I'm using [queuelib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/queuelib) and so far it's great!

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/scrapy/queuelib

Is there a way to get the current size of the FifoDiskQueue?

At the very least to know if it's empty?

Comment: type `dir(queuelib.FifoDiskQueue)` in a python interpretor (after importing queuelib) to get all the methods of the class, you may find what you're looking for

Comment: you could even use `help(queuelib.FifoDiskQueue)`, and then `help(queuelib.FifoDiskQueue.__some_method__)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`queuelib` queues support `len`, so just call `len` on one to get its size:

```
size = len(queue)
```

If you didn't realize it was `len(queue)` instead of `queue.len()`, you're probably new enough that you haven't learned that things with a nonzero `len` are considered true when converted to boolean, so

```
if queue:
    # It's not empty
```

can be used to test whether a queue is empty.

Comment: AttributeError: 'FifoDiskQueue' object has no attribute 'len'

Comment: @etayluz: `len(queue)`, not `queue.len()`, same as calling `len` on anything else.

Comment: Also if you could answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548763/python-queuelib-empty-and-clear-out-fifodiskqueue

Answer (score 1):

assuming your queue is named `q`. Does

> q.info['size']

work?

Comment: Can you please explain how you new this?

Comment: Also if you could answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548763/python-queuelib-empty-and-clear-out-fifodiskqueue

Comment: I had a look at the source code on github. The I saw the info[] map in the code.