# python queuelib: Empty and clear out FifoDiskQueue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using [queuelib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/queuelib) and so far it's great!

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/scrapy/queuelib

Is there a way to empty out the FifoDiskQueue?

Comment: Looking at what you posted on their Github issue tracker, you probably also want to know if you can peek at an element. They don't provide that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to a public API for that is to pop all elements one by one:

```
while queue:
    queue.pop()
```

This will be inefficient, but it's all they provide.

If you want to live dangerously, you can mess with the implementation details, for example by deleting files and folders manually or by doing something with the private `_cleanup` method. This would be tricky and fragile, so I don't recommend it.